# Removing .php extension with mod_rewrite works but tags pages does not

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, tags

I have such .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule (.*)/sites/([^a-zA-Z][0-9_/]*$) $1.php?sites=$2 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/sites/([0-9_/]*)/(.*) $3 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/sites/(.*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule tags_xml/(.*).xml tags/display_xml.php?tag=$1 [L]
RewriteRule news_xml/(.*).xml rss.php?site=$1 [L]
RewriteRule tags/([ÄĂ“ĹĹšÄ„Ĺ»ĹąÄ†ĹÄ™ĂłĹ‚Ĺ›Ä…ĹĽĹşÄ‡Ĺ„a-zA-Z0-9%\ ]*)/([^a-zA-Z][0-9_/]*$) tags/display.php?tag=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule tags/([ÄĂ“ĹĹšÄ„Ĺ»ĹąÄ†ĹÄ™ĂłĹ‚Ĺ›Ä…ĹĽĹşÄ‡Ĺ„a-zA-Z0-9%\ ]+) tags/display.php?tag=$1 [L]
RewriteRule news/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([^a-zA-Z][0-9]*)/(.*).html$ kom.php?id_b=$1&id_n=$2&kom_page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule news/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/(.*).html$ kom.php?id_b=$1&id_n=$2 [L]
RewriteRule news/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([^a-zA-Z][0-9]*)/(.*) $4 [L]
RewriteRule news/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/(.*) $3 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*index.php.*
```

Now when I enter

> www.domain.com/file

instead of

> www.domain.com/file.php

it works ok, but when I enter

> www.domain.com/tags/Bank

I got no such tag found error. Also other scripts in this folder just display "no such tag found".

The previous working code was:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)/sites/([^a-zA-Z][0-9_/]*$) $1.php?sites=$2 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/sites/([0-9_/]*)/(.*) $3 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/sites/(.*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule tags_xml/(.*).xml tags/display_xml.php?tag=$1 [L]
RewriteRule news_xml/(.*).xml rss.php?site=$1 [L]
RewriteRule tags/([ĘÓŁŚĄŻŹĆŃęółśążźćńa-zA-Z0-9%\ ]*)/([^a-zA-Z][0-9_/]*$) tags/display.php?tag=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule tags/([ĘÓŁŚĄŻŹĆŃęółśążźćńa-zA-Z0-9%\ ]+) tags/display.php?tag=$1 [L]
RewriteRule news/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([^a-zA-Z][0-9]*)/(.*).html$ kom.php?id_b=$1&id_n=$2&kom_page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule news/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/(.*).html$ kom.php?id_b=$1&id_n=$2 [L]
RewriteRule news/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([^a-zA-Z][0-9]*)/(.*) $4 [L]
RewriteRule news/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/(.*) $3 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*index.php.*
```

Comment: "The previous working code" - if it works, why not use it?

Comment: It works for the tags, but not for removing .php from files.

Comment: Is all of your code necessary for this question? Could you strip the unnecessary lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to just add at the end:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: But I still guess my answare gave you the help you needed to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Update:
OK, after reading through your htaccess again, I notice that you use the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

On some systems this will point relative to your filesystem, so maybe adding DOCUMENT_ROOT will work for you. Like so:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: This is just translation mistake here. It's correctly done and it's not working.

Comment: the tagi/display part of your line?

Comment: I needed to translate it here from polish.

Comment: I would be very very careful if you're not directly copying and pasting the problem code. It's understandably necessary in this case, but just a heads up that you might be overlooking an error in your code and typing differently here.

Comment: @Bjorne - with your code both pages without php are not working and tags are not working too, so we need to find better solution

Comment: Maybe we can exclude /tags directory ?